# html5 javascript webgl finding x and y coordinates

Tags: html, webgl

I wonder if you could/would help me.
I have a page (java script/ html5/webgl)
and I am displaying a set of points,
 then when the user pressess on a point I would lik to find the x and y coordinates that I set in the first place.(range of 0 to 1)
 what I get from the even is the x and y screen coordinates (pixals)
from even.offsetX and so.
what is the right math to get to the acsual points?

please help

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

In regular OpenGL, the command you need is gluUnProject:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml

For WebGL, you will have to roll your own since it doesn't have any fixed function pipeline support.  Assuming that you are using standard transformation matrices, you can just modify the formulas in that man page.  It would be hard to say anything more specific without the details of you set up your coordinate systems.